# Magento multiple stores on one server?

Tags: magento, themes, e-commerce, store

We have a Magento commerce store with a database of around 700 products. The store has one URL and one theme. It doesn't have any other language versions or anything like that.

I am looking into our options for having a new URL for a second company (all under one company umbrella) with a different theme. So essentially there would be one database in use by two Magento stores with different themes.

```
originalstore.com
newstore.com
```

Is this possible with the Community edition?

Also, if it is possible can the newstore.com have different prices for the same products as originalstore.com?

Any help or suggestions would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add new websites in System -> Manage Stores.  Websites can have separate configurations and products and still be in the same database.  After you've added the website, you can make magneto auto load it by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newstore.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:yourNewStoreCode]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Comment: Can each site have their own pricing strategy?

Comment: They can, after you've added new websites, there will be a dropdown on the product view page that will let you choose which store you are editing the price for.